# Node-Canvas on Vercel Serverless Function - Serverless Function exceeds the maximum size of 50mb

Tags: canvas, next.js, fabricjs, vercel, node-canvas

In my Next.js project, I am using fabric and fabricjs-react as a wrapper over fabric to allow users to drop images into my canvas. Now one of fabric's dependency happens to be  `node_modules/canvas/build` which has a compressed size of 42.82 MB. I have tried using `@napi-rs/canvas` to replace the `canvas` package in my package.json but it lead to `Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/canvas.node'`. I am trying to use `getServerSideProps` in my concerned page. But it only leads to a build error on Vercel. I am using 12.3.1 version of **`next`** along with `5.3.0` version of **`fabric`** and `2.11.2` version of **`canvas`** package.  [image: Hereby attached is a screenshot of what I get in my Vercel logs while building the project]

Is there any way I can trim down this dependency size or only import the parts of the package I need in this API route? If using `@napi-rs/canvas` is a workaround, how do I solve the `Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/canvas.node'`. given by fabric ?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue and found a workaround that doesn't break the fabricjs functionalities in my case.

Update your next.config.js with the following:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "**",
      },
    ],
  },
  experimental: {
    legacyBrowsers: false,
    outputFileTracingExcludes: ['**canvas**']
  },
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.externals = [...config.externals, "canvas", "jsdom"]
    return config
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

The key addition here is the `outputFileTracingExcludes: ['**canvas**']` which excludes the canvas dependency during the build. In my tests, this didn't break any fabricjs functionalities. Make sure to test it thoroughly in your use case. I hope this helps.